# Is there a site (or app) like Beer Advocate that lets me give just an overall rating?

Tags: buying, resources, recommendations

Beer Advocate used to allow you to give an overall rating for a beer, rather than giving score breakdowns (appearance, smell, mouth feel, etc).  They have recently [changed this](http://www.beeradvocate.com/community/threads/beeradvocate-returns-to-its-roots-rating-system-revamped.238804/) and you can only supply a rating if you rate all the factors.  That makes sense if you're a site owner trying to gather better data, but it's not so great for the casual beer-drinker who just wants to keep track of what she's had and how she liked it.

The value of a site like Beer Advocate, rather than just keeping a file on disk, is having access to the descriptions (including categories like "winter warmer" and "amber ale" and suchlike), other items from those breweries (useful when looking at a menu, or shopping), and, out of curiosity, the variance between my rating and the average for people who rated that beer. Also, I want to be able to see and add ratings from multiple locations, so if I just used a file it would have to live in the cloud somewhere.  Alternatively, I'd be happy to use an app on my Android phone.

What's the easiest way for me to track what I've had, with information about the beers (and breweries) and my own ratings?  I don't care if my ratings are shared with the world; I'm happy to contribute them if that's helpful, but I'm looking for a way that *I* can track information about *my own* tastes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RateBeer is the other big rating site.  It also has a 5 point rating system but you can also just "tick" beers 1-5 stars, which may be helpful for you.

There's also Untappd which is pretty popular.  It operates more on a 4square-style check-in system and has a lot of social features as well as badges for various types of beer, origins, location, timing, etc.  But their rating system is a simple 1-5 stars with an optional notes field and location tagging.  They also include a recommendation system but it doesn't take locality into account making it largely useless since the majority of the beers they'll recommend are impossible to find in your area.

There are a few smaller ones kicking around as well.  A buddy of mine did [littlebeerbook.com](http://littlebeerbook.com), which is fairly up your alley based on the description.  However it's pretty rough on mobile, and even outside of that the User Experience isn't the best.  Work is being done, but it's slow going with day jobs and families and all that.  So if you don't mind the interface, it'll track what you want pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  I've just signed up with RateBeer and posted a question there asking if it's possible to import data from Beer Advocate ('cause doing that by hand would be rough).  That seems closer to what I'm looking for than Untapped, so I'm trying RB first.

Comment: Untapped also has an API - so you can access your info via other sites such as [BrewFeed](http://www.brewfeed.com/) as well.

Answer (score 4):

There is [Untappd](https://untappd.com/home), which is a social network for beer drinkers (web and app). Quite straightforward, actually. You check you beer in, rate it and leave a short comment (like Twitter). And you see a timeline with your check-ins and your friend's ones.

The rate is what you're looking for, an overall score from 0 to 5 (multiples of 0.25).

It's nice for keeping a log of what you have had and see what you friends are having, too. But, it's very simple when it comes to features, don't expect much of it.

Comment: Untappd is a great site for logging what you've tried, but unfortunately I haven't found many people interested in using it so the social aspect hasn't worked out too well.

Comment: Yeah, the same for me, just a few friends use it, but I find it useful for me, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Beer Citizen allows you to rate Appearance, scent, taste and mouthfeel. You can look at individual reviews or get an average rating from everyone who has reviewed the beer. Each beer has brew facts and show you similar beers to the one you are reviewing. 
Great app

Comment: But can I instead just give a one-number rating if that's all I want to bother with?

Comment: Sorry misread your post. You can add notes for yourself in Beer Citizen. Untapped works well for what you are looking for.